# Countif value is equal to cell and another cell in the row across range is greater than 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

In column D id like to count how many times the value in H is mentioned in the H:H range if in range E:E any of the rows that contain the value H, are greater than 1 in range E:E.

So for example, if any "dental wax" values have a Status greater than 1, id like to count that in D.

Goals Example:

[image: What im trying to do get]

Preferably looking for a formula. Thank you for any and all help.

I apologize in advance if this could have been worded simpler, tired.

Comment: `=countifs(h:h, "*"&h2&"*", e:e, ">1")`

Comment: that doesnt do it. I get 10 on something that doesnt have any statuses greater than 0

Comment: @Jeeped's formula should work. Can you provide a more detailed example of the wrong output?

Comment: Are the `-` actual `-` or a mask for `0`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
=COUNTIFS(H$2:H,H2,E$2:E,">1")
```

Comment: @GalAbra it does in Google Sheets which was tagged for this question.